# Compile exe with static (.lib) and dynamic (.dll) libraries in same solution - visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, linker-errors

I have a visual studio solution that has various projects: static lib project (creates *.lib file), dynamic lib project (creates *.dll file) and one exe project (that creates *.exe file)

The exe projects uses (or better say - depends on) the static and dynamic libs.

I added the path to the dll files in configuration properties -> Linker -> General, and the name of the .lib files in configuration properties -> Linker -> Input.

The problem is when I try to build the exe project I have the same error from the linker:

> LNK2019 unresolved external symbol ... referenced in function ...

This error appears for every usage on dll function.

What is missing in the project configuration, so I the linker will be satisfied?

**Edit**: - example of the desired function to export:

```
extern "C" {
    void foo1(int i);
    void foo2(int i);
    ...
}
```

Comment: _"...dynamic lib project (creates *.dll file) ..."_: should also create .lib files which are the import/export definitions these need to be linked with.

Comment: What do you mean? I need to create dll and lib from the same project?

Comment: No a default Visual Studio DLL project will automatically output a *.DLL and an import/export *.LIB.  The DLL contains the code and the LIB is just a stub library which references the DLL.  You then link with the library to use the functions in the DLL.  At runtime the stub code in the LIB causes the system loader to be invoked to load the DLL and the fix-up the entry points.

Comment: But I don't see any .lib files that created from dll project. Only .pdb and .lik

Comment: where, in which *lib* must be this unresolved symbol ? you add this lib to linker input ? this symbol (exactly name) exist in this lib ?

Comment: When I try to compile the exe project, the unresolved symbol error happens for all dll functions that I try to use. I didn't add the *.dll  to input of the linker, since only ".lib" files should be there. (when I put .dll files there - it complains about corrupted file)

Comment: How have you marked the functions in the DLL header files for import/export?

Comment: extern "C" {
... 
...
} It works perfect with linux, but not with windows.

Comment: lookup `__declspec` `import` and `export` on MSDN use conditional `#define`s for importing exporting and Linux differences.

Comment: Or use a `.DEF` file to define the exports.

Answer (score 0):

To enable the exe project using the dlls - I needed to add __declspec(dllexport) to the API functions:

```
#define LIBRARY_API __declspec(dllexport)
extern "C" {
    LIBRARY_API void foo1(int i);
    LIBRARY_API void foo2(int i);
    ...
}
```

Then the compiler created also .lib for every .dll project, and I could add the .lib files to linker -> Input in the project properties.